# How to add specific categories to woocommerce product variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am adding a custom field to woocommerce product variations to attach additional product categories to product variations. Everything works, during the save process the terms are updated in wp_term_relationships table however, a bit later in the save operation the terms are overwritten again with the parent product ones.

[image: custom meta box]

I am using the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_custom_field_variations', 99, 2 );
 
function save_custom_field_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
    $custom_categories = $_POST['variation_product_cat'][$variation_id];
    if ( isset( $custom_categories ) && !empty( $custom_categories )) {
        wp_set_post_terms( $variation_id, $custom_categories, 'product_cat' );    
    }   
}
```

I have also tried a different hook with the same result:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'save_custom_field_variations_2', 99, 1 );
 
function save_custom_field_variations_2( $post_id ) {
    foreach($_POST['variation_product_cat'] as $variation_id => $custom_categories)
    if ( isset( $custom_categories ) && !empty( $custom_categories )) {
        $response = wp_set_post_terms( $variation_id, $custom_categories, 'product_cat' );    
    }   
}
```

Any tips on what process is overwriting my changes are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was one of the plugins that was overwriting the changes (found out by disabling all and then enabling them one by one)